# Sorting two column in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have a table - persons

```
id | First Name  | Last Name
-----------------------------'
1    AA             BB
2    EE             DD
3    CC             FF
```

Here , i want to display first name and last name in 1 column.

```
Such that output would be 
----------------------
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF

Can i also display it as 
------------------
1 AA
1 BB
3 CC
2 DD
2 EE
3 FF
```

Using Mysql query ??

Comment: and what did you try? we are here to help not to work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `union all`:

```
select first_name as name from persons union all
select last_name from persons
order by name;
```

EDIT:

For the revised question:

```
select id, first_name as name from persons union all
select id, last_name from persons
order by name;
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Can u please tell if that is possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the result based on the id. Then,

**Query**

```
select t.name from(
    select id, firstname as name
    from tblPersons
    union all
    select id, lastname as name
    from tblPersons
)t
order by t.id, t.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select first_name from person 

union 

select last_name from person
)
t 
order by first_name
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include some supporting explanation as to why this answers the question